# css: exclude (hide) specific area from element

Tags: html, css

With CSS3 `clip-path` option I can easily clip element so that only specified area will be visible. It's cool, but is there a way to exclude an area so that everything **except** specified path will be visible?

Here is an example of what I want to do. I need to cut a circle out:
[image]

Placing a circle over is not an option because I need the underlying background to be visible.

AFAIK one way to do it is by using canvas, but is it possible with pure CSS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure it's possible.  Use `clip-path`!  Imagine your `div` is piece of paper and `clip-path` is a pair of scissors.  If you wanted to cut out a circle in the middle, you'd cut around the edges, along a line into the middle, around a circle, and back to the edge along the same line.

I hacked together a python script that outputs the CSS.  Apologies for the style...

```
import math

# radius in percent of width
radius = 0.25
# xy pos in percent
xPos = 0.5
yPos = 0.5
# number of points around the circle
# size of css is approx proportional to this 
smooth = 50



# from here, just go around the outline of the shape

x = []
y = []

x.append(0)
y.append(0)

x.append(0)
y.append(1)

x.append(xPos - radius)
y.append(1)

x.append(xPos - radius)
y.append(yPos)

angleZero = math.pi
increment = 2 * math.pi / smooth

numDigits = 3

for k in range(0, smooth):
 angle = angleZero - k * increment
 x.append( round( xPos + radius * math.cos(angle), numDigits ) )
 y.append( round( yPos - radius * math.sin(angle), numDigits ) )

x.append(xPos - radius)
y.append(yPos)

x.append(xPos - radius)
y.append(1)

x.append(1)
y.append(1)

x.append(1)
y.append(0)

cssValue = "polygon(";
for k in range(0, len(x) - 1):
  cssValue += str( abs(x[k]*100) ) + "% " + str( abs(y[k]*100) ) + "%, "
cssValue += str( abs(x[len(x) - 1]*100) ) + "% " + str(abs( y[len(x) - 1]*100) ) + "%);"

property = "clip-path: "
spaces = "    "
print(".excludeCircle{");
print(spaces + "-webkit-"+property + cssValue)
print(spaces + property + cssValue)
print("}")
```

Here's what it looks like:

```css
.excludeCircle{
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 100%, 25.0% 100%, 25.0% 50.0%, 25.0% 50.0%, 25.2% 46.9%, 25.8% 43.8%, 26.8% 40.8%, 28.1% 38.0%, 29.8% 35.3%, 31.8% 32.9%, 34.1% 30.7%, 36.6% 28.9%, 39.4% 27.4%, 42.3% 26.2%, 45.3% 25.4%, 48.4% 25.0%, 51.6% 25.0%, 54.7% 25.4%, 57.7% 26.2%, 60.6% 27.4%, 63.4% 28.9%, 65.9% 30.7%, 68.2% 32.9%, 70.2% 35.3%, 71.9% 38.0%, 73.2% 40.8%, 74.2% 43.8%, 74.8% 46.9%, 75.0% 50.0%, 74.8% 53.1%, 74.2% 56.2%, 73.2% 59.2%, 71.9% 62.0%, 70.2% 64.7%, 68.2% 67.1%, 65.9% 69.3%, 63.4% 71.1%, 60.6% 72.6%, 57.7% 73.8%, 54.7% 74.6%, 51.6% 75.0%, 48.4% 75.0%, 45.3% 74.6%, 42.3% 73.8%, 39.4% 72.6%, 36.6% 71.1%, 34.1% 69.3%, 31.8% 67.1%, 29.8% 64.7%, 28.1% 62.0%, 26.8% 59.2%, 25.8% 56.2%, 25.2% 53.1%, 25.0% 50.0%, 25.0% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
    clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 100%, 25.0% 100%, 25.0% 50.0%, 25.0% 50.0%, 25.2% 46.9%, 25.8% 43.8%, 26.8% 40.8%, 28.1% 38.0%, 29.8% 35.3%, 31.8% 32.9%, 34.1% 30.7%, 36.6% 28.9%, 39.4% 27.4%, 42.3% 26.2%, 45.3% 25.4%, 48.4% 25.0%, 51.6% 25.0%, 54.7% 25.4%, 57.7% 26.2%, 60.6% 27.4%, 63.4% 28.9%, 65.9% 30.7%, 68.2% 32.9%, 70.2% 35.3%, 71.9% 38.0%, 73.2% 40.8%, 74.2% 43.8%, 74.8% 46.9%, 75.0% 50.0%, 74.8% 53.1%, 74.2% 56.2%, 73.2% 59.2%, 71.9% 62.0%, 70.2% 64.7%, 68.2% 67.1%, 65.9% 69.3%, 63.4% 71.1%, 60.6% 72.6%, 57.7% 73.8%, 54.7% 74.6%, 51.6% 75.0%, 48.4% 75.0%, 45.3% 74.6%, 42.3% 73.8%, 39.4% 72.6%, 36.6% 71.1%, 34.1% 69.3%, 31.8% 67.1%, 29.8% 64.7%, 28.1% 62.0%, 26.8% 59.2%, 25.8% 56.2%, 25.2% 53.1%, 25.0% 50.0%, 25.0% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
}

img{
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}

body{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div style="position: absolute;">
  This is text in the background. This is text in the background. This is text in the background. This is text in the background. This is text in the background. This is text in the background. This is text in the background. This is text in the background. This is text in the background. This is text in the background. This is text in the background. This is text in the background. This is text in the background. This is text in the background. This is text in the background. This is text in the background. This is text in the background. This is text in the background. This is text in the background. This is text in the background. This is text in the background. This is text in the background. This is text in the background. This is text in the background. This is text in the background. This is text in the background. This is text in the background. This is text in the background. This is text in the background. This is text in the background. This is text in the background. This is text in the background. This is text in the background. This is text in the background. This is text in the background.
</div>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2ETg.png" class="excludeCircle"/>
```

Edit: One issue with this method is that it really makes an oval.  You could fix this by using px in the circle (if you know the min-size of the element) or by having an x radius and a y radius (if you know the relative sizes).  If you know nothing, you'll need some js...

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a fiddle, but this might help **if the background is an image**.  Place a circle over, and treat the background as a sprite.  Comment out the `content` div to see the full background image:

```css
#container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200');
  text-align:center;
}
#content {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  background: silver;
  text-align: center;
  display:inline-block;
}
#circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200') 150px 50px;
  background-position: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 58px;
  left: 158px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
    <br>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum amet sint dolor etc.</p>
    <p>This is your main content area</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div id="circle"></div>
```